# Downloading a snap file for installation on a PC not connected to the Internet

Tags: snap, offline, snap-store

I would like to download a snap file in order to install an application on a PC **not connected** to the Internet. This application is on the snap store. Please do you know how to do it? Thank you for your reply ...

Comment: Can you install the same snap package on another internet-connected computer?